# Oracle SQL TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert the following a column that has content in the following format from nvarchar2(100) to DATE or DATETIME:

```
8/21/2018 1:34
9/4/2018 11:22
10/15/2018 16:34
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the correct string format to use is for the query?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Side comment, storing dates as strings is a bad idea and will cause many headaches. If there's any way you can move from storing dates as strings, I recommend doing so as soon as you can.

Comment: Just curious - since the strings only contain digits, spaces, slash and colon (`/` and `:`), why was it necessary to set the data type as national character set string? `NVARCHAR2` instead of the standard `VARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DATE()` should work:

```
select to_date('9/4/2018 11:22', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
```